# nomad multiline environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, nomad

Is there a way to have a multiline environment variable in a nomad template?  Trying it directly gives an error about not being able to find the closing quote.

In the docs the only function that's mentioned is `| toJSON`, but that translates the line feeds into `\n` so the receiving end needs to do a search-and-replace or some "unJSON" function.

I tried using HEREDOC syntax in the template, but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Seem we can generate multiline file using nomad templates data with heredoc and lets the service read that file.

Comment: @gumelaragum can you provide an example in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a here document works fine:

```
job "example" {
  datacenters = ["dc1"]
  type = "service"
  group "cache" {
    task "redis" {
      driver = "docker"
      config {
        image = "redis:7"
      }
      env {
        EXAMPLE = <<EOF
multiline
varibale
is
here
EOF
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's been half a year now so I don't recall exactly what I was doing, but maybe my issue was indenting the `EOF`.